# SQL triggers not returning expected values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Using the world database I have to create a trigger that will update the population of a `country` (table) when the `city` (also table) of a population is updated and pull the old results into a new table `ancien_population`:

```
CREATE TABLE ancien_population (Name VARCHAR(100), population int(11));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER city_pop
AFTER UPDATE ON city
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO ancien_population (Name, population) VALUES ('City', old.population);
UPDATE ancien_population set Name = (select Name from city where Population = new.population) where population = old.population;
UPDATE country SET population = (population + (new.population - old.population)) WHERE country.code in (select CountryCode from city where city.population = new.population);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The sub query returns more than one row so it gives us an error. We need the trigger to pull the name of the city as well as the old population.

Comment: Cities can have the same population, so this doesn't seem like the right logic.